# jquery.ajax()+PHP return value begin with space

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I use Ajax to request data from a PHP script, but the return data always begin with one space-both firebug and alert() shows that.
JS part:

```
$("#onVSearch").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"/j/getVideo",
            data:{"url":$('.sv input').val()},
            success:function(data)
            {
             alert(data.substr(0,1));//this gives blank
             alert(data.substr(0,2));//this will give 0
            }
        })
    })
```

And PHP part:

```
if(isset($_GET['url']))
{
 echo 0;// I've tried both echo 0 and echo '0'
}
```

I thought it was caused by the encoding difference between the PHP file and the js file, but they are all set to UTF-8 without BOM.
What else can the reason be?

**UPDATE:**
I now use JSON format to pass data from PHP to JS, and it works well... Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite certain in one of your PHP files, you have an erroneous space outside of `<?php` and `?>`.

Comment: I just found that the space only appears in js scripts. If I directly visit j/getVideo?url=d in my browser there's no space.

Answer (score 0):

You must look a bigger part of PHP code. Maybe a space or new-line outside of the  tags could be causing it. Also obviously look if you don't echo anything anywhere else.